# how to query by values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

My collection looks like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("520c8976586f12c80900301d"),
"IDENTITY" : "ae4ff1546ecfe6ce6e8ebb2d870d57fb",
"NAME" : "Winmain Yao",
"TYPE" : "COMPANY",
"PUBLIC" : 1,
"BACKGROUND" : null,
"CONTACT" : {
  "PHONE" : {
    "WORK" : "18630283895",
    "HOME" : "188837283"
},
"EMAIL" : {
  "DEFAULT00001" : "zxwinmain@gmail.com"
},
"IM" : [],
"SITE" : [],
"ADDRESS" : [],
"SOCIAL" : []
},
"RELATION" : {
  "ACCOUNT" : "16713a29767fa4e8f139dfb249900c07",
  "USER" : "84a9e7a8e5f3a13d411cfa8ff4a62a50"
},
"CREATED" : 1376553334,
"UPDATED" : 0,
"DELETED" : 0
}
```

Now I want to get the customer who's phone = 18630283895, how can I do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This type of question has been covered many many many many times, please do some Google searching before posting here however:  `$db->collection->find(array('$or'=>array(array( 'CONTACT.PHONE.WORK'=>18630283895),array('CONTACT.PHONE.HOME'=>18630283895))))` this one time

Comment: Hi @Sammaye, I'm sorry the question is not too clear, the phone number has many of types, I want to search the value = 18630283895, whatever it's type is work or home or some else.

Comment: You have chosen the wrong schema here then, you need an array of pairs, like so: `PHONE:[{name:'home',number:186707076},{name:'work',number:59569696}]` That way you can just query on `PHONE.number` and it will pick all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following:

```
"PHONE" : {
    "WORK" : "18630283895",
    "HOME" : "188837283"
},
```

Is the **wrong** approach. As you invariably will have further types of phone numbers, you have ended up with a "key that is actually a value". This makes it difficult to query (and index). The better approach to this is:

```
"PHONE" : [
    { type: "WORK", number: "18630283895" },
    { type: "HOME", number: "188837283" },
],
```

Then you can very easily index it with:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { "PHONE.number": 1 } );
```

And query for numbers with:

```
db.collection.find( { "PHONE.number" : "18630283895" } );
```